# How do I find quest in Just Cause 2

Tags: just-cause-2

I've done one of 2 quests but now I just can't find any I go to cities and I never see any quests.  Where are they, how do I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to your map you'll see all the quests that are available to you at the time.

If you've only done 2, you probably have maybe only one quest you can do, because it sounds like you might still be in the starting storyline quests.

Comment: But I'm kind of lost how do I know where it is?

Comment: You should have a marker on the map of your current location, and if you have the guy with the helicopter he should be able to drop you off at the location.